# mysql odbc questions

Tags: odbc, mysql-connector

i'd like to use the mysql odbc driver for connecting to my mysql database via my own app.
the problem is that it seems very unstable - i keep getting errors like:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.8]MySQL server has gone away
```

it seems to be something like a session timeout.

so here's my questions:
- what is causing those errors?
- is there a way to fix it for getting stable connections?
- is it recommended at all using it for coding windows software?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're opening the connection once and leaving it open.  At some point, the connection either times out, or some network hiccup is causing the connection to be invalid/closed. The best way to do database access is to open the connection when you need to do work, then close it.  Or, alternatively, change your code to support re-connecting when you encounter an error.

Based on discussion in the comments below, I would suggest dumping the access database to a csv file, then using something like PHPMySql to import the data into MySQL.

You can use the [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) tool to import large databases dumps into MySQL. (via [this site](http://www.wanderings.net/notebook/Main/HowToImportLargeMySQLDataFiles))

Comment: the problem is, it's also happening with a converter called "MS Access to MySQL" i'm using (for writing access into my mysql database) - it also terminates with that error after 60 seconds (i think) ..

Comment: What do you mean by a converter, exactly?

Comment: it's a freeware for converting a ms access database into mysql: http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

Comment: This is just to do a one way conversion, right?  And the connection is timing out while converting?

Comment: yep exactly .. i've already tried doing database queries during conversion for keeping the connection alive - didn't help ..

Comment: Where's the instance of mysql running? Is it local or on a remote server?  Also, how large is the Access database.  If it's huge, this tool might not support large databases.

Comment: it's running all locally - the access database is ~2 gb.
i think i found out something meanwhile: it seems like that the reason for the timeouts is existence of blob field inside the database - i just converted a different database (a bit smaller) and it worked without problems.

Comment: The reason executing queries during the conversion didn't help is the program has one connection and the queries you're executing would be on a separate connection.  Your connection is still valid, but the importer's connection times out.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that tool has a "create dump" option.  Use that then import the dump file to MySQL instead of the live transfer.

Comment: i've tried that too - but phpmyadmin is importing for hours and seems to hang :(

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial alternatives out there -

[OpenLink Single-tier ODBC Driver for MySQL](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql-st/)